# Change BlackBerry's callIncoming() more then one time while call incoming

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm working on app. that gets info. about the caller by it's number.
I have a slight problem that while cheking the info. about the caller the phone isn't showing the basic incoming call screen.
I want to present an incoming call screen with one extra label.
First the label's text will be 'Searching', and after I got the search result I want to change the label's text according to the info. I found.
I tried to use phoneScreenPortrait.updateDisplay(), but nothing happend.

The code:

```
public void callIncoming(int callId)
{
    ScreenModel screenModel = new ScreenModel(callId);
    PhoneScreen phoneScreenPortrait = screenModel.getPhoneScreen(PhoneScreen.PORTRAIT, PhoneScreen.INCOMING);
```

```
String resName = "";
String callNum = Phone.getCall(callId).getDisplayPhoneNumber();

if( Phone.getCall(callId).getContact() != null ) //Contact found
{
    screenModel.sendAllDataToScreen();
    return;
}

LabelField callerName;
callerName = new LabelField( "Searching" ) 
{
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.paint(g);
    }
}; 

callerName.setFont(phoneScreenPortrait.getCallerInfoFont());
phoneScreenPortrait.add(callerName);

screenModel.sendAllDataToScreen();

try
{
    resName = getName( callNum ); // Get's the name with my function
}
catch( Exception ex )
{
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
}

if( resName == null )
    resName = "No match..";

callerName.setText( resName );
phoneScreenPortrait.updateDisplay();
```

}
Thanks,
Rotem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I managed to solve it myself..

After I set the LabelField's text I added those lines:

```
phoneScreen.updateDisplay();
phoneScreen.doPaint();
screenModel.sendAllDataToScreen();
```